# Pagination Solutions for multiple queries with multiple tabs Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Hey guys so I have a projects page on our website that utilizes tabs to separate multiple different project types across different tabs. Each tab runs its own query   by category, ordering the projects in that category by date and displaying: The title, a date, views, author, a small extract of the post and a featured image.

The problem now is that I have too many posts per tab and you have to scroll down a long way to see older projects. What is the best solution for breaking each project post by category into pages of 4 posts. Is a better solution to run a single loop, separate the projects into other tabs by category and the paginate the page? Or is there a more eloquent solution?

Here is my main Project page with tabs:

```
          <div id="categoryTabs">
            <ul id="news_style1_tabs" class="tabs">
                <li><a href="#mining">Mining</a></li>
                <li><a href="#ong">Oil & Gas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#energy">Energy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#infs">Infastructure</a></li>
                <li><a href="#global">Global</a></li>
            </ul>

<section id="news_style1_body" class="news_body"> 

<div class="tab_all" id="mining">
<?php get_template_part('page-projectsTabs-mining'); ?>
</div>

<div class="tab_all" id="ong">
<?php get_template_part('page-projectsTabs-ong'); ?>
</div>

 <div class="tab_all" id="energy">
<?php get_template_part('page-projectsTabs-energy'); ?>
</div>

 <div class="tab_all" id="infs">
<?php get_template_part('page-projectsTabs-infs'); ?>
</div>
 <div class="tab_all" id="global">
<?php get_template_part('page-projectsTabs-glob'); ?>
</div>
</section>
```

and here is an example of one of the tabs with a category

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args_mining = array(   'post_type'     => 'projects', 
    'status'        => 'published', 
    'category_name'     => 'Mining',
    'posts_per_page'=> 4,
    'orderby'   => 'post_date',
    'order'         => 'DESC'
);
$get_mining = new WP_Query($args_mining);
if($get_mining->have_posts()){
    while($get_mining->have_posts()) : $get_mining->the_post(); 
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_thumbnail_id($get_mining->ID),'home-feature');?>

                <article>
                  <div class="pic"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="w_hover img-link img-wrap"><?php echo $image; ?><span class="link-gallery"></span> </a> </div>
                  <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                  <ul class="icons">
                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post_date"><?php echo get_the_time('d M, Y', $get_mining);?></a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post_views"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'views',true);?></a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post_submitted"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'Author',true);?></a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="comments_count"></a></li>
                  </ul>
                   <div class="text"><?php echo get_excerpt(900,$get_mining); ?></div>
                </article>

<?php endwhile;
}?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Any help and advice will be good. Please note at the moment I have about 5 tabs

EDIT 1: Added my Pagination Function in my functions.php

Below is the code for pagination found in my functions.php

```
 function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='') {

  if (empty($pagerange)) {
    $pagerange = 2;
  }

  global $paged;
  if (empty($paged)) {
    $paged = 1;
  }
  if ($numpages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        if(!$numpages) {
            $numpages = 1;
        }
}
    //Check page number and store $pageUp and $pageDown appropriately
  if($paged == '1'){
    $pageDown = $paged + 1;
    $pageUp = $paged +2;
    $prev = get_previous_posts_page_link($pageDown);
    $next = get_next_posts_page_link($pageUp);


  }
  elseif(($paged >= 2)&&(!$paged==$numpages)){
    $pageDown = $paged -1;
    $pagedUp = $paged +1;
    $prev = get_previous_posts_page_link();
    $next = get_next_posts_page_link();
  }
  elseif($paged == $numpages){
    $pageDown = $paged -2;
    $pageUp = $paged -1;
    $prev = get_previous_posts_page_link($pageDown);
    $next = get_next_posts_page_link($pageUp);
  }  



  $pagination_args = array(
    'base'            => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
    'format'          => 'page/%#%',
    'total'           => $numpages,
    'current'         => $paged,
    'show_all'        => False,
    'end_size'        => 1,
    'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
    'prev_next'       => False,
    'prev_text'       => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text'       => __('&raquo;'),
    'type'            => 'plain',
    'add_args'        => false,
    'add_fragment'    => ''
  );

  $paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

  if ($paginate_links) {

    echo '<div id ="nav_pages">'; 
    echo '<div class="prev_first"></div>'; 
        //echo '   <a href="'.$paginate_links.'" class="next">Next</a>';
        echo '<div class="pages"';
        echo'<ul>';
        if($paged==1){      
            $pageDown = $paged + 1;
            $pageUp = $paged +2;
            $prev = get_next_posts_page_link();
            $next = get_next_posts_page_link();
            echo' <li class="current"><a href="" title="">'.$paged.'</a></li>';
            echo'<li><a href="'.$prev.'" title="'.$prev.'">'.$pageDown.'</a></li>';
            //echo'<li><a href="'.$next.'" title="'.$next.'">'.$pageUp.'</a></li>';
            }
        elseif(($paged >= 2)&&($paged!=$numpages)){
            $pageDown = $paged -1;
            $pageUp = $paged +1;
            $prev = get_previous_posts_page_link();
            $next = get_next_posts_page_link();
            echo'<li><a href="'.$prev.'" title="'.$prev.'">'.$pageDown.'</a></li>';
            echo' <li class="current"><a href="" title="">'.$paged.'</a></li>';
            echo'<li><a href="'.$next.'" title="">'.$pageUp.'</a></li>';
        }

        elseif($paged==$numpages){
            $pageDown = $paged -2;
            $pageUp = $paged -1;
            $prev = get_previous_posts_page_link();
            $next = get_next_posts_page_link();
            echo'<li><a href="'.$prev.'" title="'.$prev.'">'.$pageUp.'</a></li>';
            //echo'<li><a href="'.$next.'" title="'.$next.'">'.$pageUp.'</a></li>';
            echo' <li class="current"><a href="" title="">'.$paged.'</a></li>';


        }   
         //echo $paginate_links;
         echo '</ul>';
          echo '<div class="page_x_of_y">Page <span>' . $paged . '</span> of <span>' . $numpages . '</span></div> ';

        echo '</div>';
  } 

}

//End of pagination
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code for paged :

```
$paged1 = isset( $_GET['paged1'] ) ? (int) $_GET['paged1'] : 1;
```

and use it in query like below :

```
$args_mining = array(   'post_type'     => 'projects', 
    'status'        => 'published', 
    'category_name'     => 'Mining',
    'posts_per_page'=> 4,
    'orderby'   => 'post_date',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'paged'    => $paged1
);
```

then for pagination use below code after endwhile;

```
$pag_args1 = array(
'prev_text'    => __('<'),
'next_text'    => __('>'),
'show_all' => true,
'base'         => '' . $url . '?paged1=%#%',                
    'format'  => '?paged1=%#%',
    'current' => $paged1,
    'total'   => $get_mining->max_num_pages); 
    echo paginate_links( $pag_args1 );
```

Note: (use `$paged1` and `$args_mining` as different variable for different query for categotry )

Comment: So i could use `$paged_mining` etc for the paging queries? Is there a way to use one paging function to page to all of categories at once since all of the tabs and categories load at the same time?

Comment: no for example for `Oil and Gas` use `$paged2` and `$args_oil_gas` and so on for other categories like : `$page3` and `$args_your_cat_name` and so on.

Comment: So this way I can have multiple pages for all the categories? So if i go to the next page ti will show me 4 more posts for each category? Im gonna try this out and see how I go

Comment: use my code as where i suggested in your existing code

Comment: So this almost seems to work. I have a pagination function in my functions.php called `custom_pagination`. I used this with the variable `$paged1` but it seems to be showing the same 4 posts for the mining section. You can see my edited question for my pagination function.

Comment: Please upvote answer and mark as helpful so it can be helpful for others

Comment: Can you help me figure out a way to make this work with the right posts on the subsequent pages?

Comment: This works perfectly now. I just have to figure out how to wrap my own html around the numbers. Thanks